# Creating a new folder with a datetime

Tags: python

I want to create a new folder using the current datetime, but I get an error:

```
import datetime
import os
x = datetime.datetime.now()
os.mkdir(x)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sepeh\Desktop\F-1\mkdir.py", line 6, in <module> 
    os.mkdir(x)
TypeError: mkdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not datetime
```

Comment: The error message is clear.  a `datetime` is not a string.  What string do you want to generate for the folder name?  See [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format the time.

Comment: A field that is equal to the current date and time.
Changing 'datetime.datetime' to 'datetime.strftime' still did not solve the problem!

Comment: Please *read* the link and how to use the function!  You need a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).  Learn to fish instead of asking for fish :)

Comment: Please answer the question! I don't have time for fishing!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good format for date designations is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

This format makes sure the files are displayed in chronological order when a directory listing is done. Always having zero-padded decimal numbers for month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds is important to maintain the sorting.

To get a string from datetime in this format it would look like:

```py
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

For creating the file, I would recommend using the Python [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)

An example of putting this all together would be:

```py
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

Path(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")).mkdir()
```

If that directory name is hard to read then the numbers can be split with some formatting. For example:

```py
Path(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%dT%H-%M-%S")).mkdir()
```

Comment: I am really grateful
My problem is solved